# External drive does not mount after plug off without eject

Tags: external-disk, hdd, diskutil

I accidentally unplugged my hard drive without properly ejecting it, and now the drive does not mount when plugged in.

What can I do to make it work again?

I can see the disk in `lsusb` and `diskutil list`.

So far, I've tried:

- `sudo diskutil unmountDisk force /dev/disk2`
- `sudo diskutil unmount force /dev/disk2`
- Reboot with disk.
- Reboot without disk.

It seems that the disk is working because it's vibrating very slowly, but I can't see it in Finder.

Comment: I have tried all the above options, but still unable to mount and/or eject the disk. When I attempt to run the First Aid, I get the following: **Repairing file system,
Volume is already unmounted.
Performing fsck_exfat -y -x /dev/rdisk2s1
File system check exit code is 1.
Restoring the original state found as unmounted.
File system verify or repair failed.
Operation failed…** Any idea on how to proceed next on this?

Answer (score 76):

SOLVED. Had this problem today. OLD external drive, had its own power source, plugged into a surge protector. I hit the power button on the surge protector when I was unplugging something else, and the drive was turned off while in use. I turned it back on and it sounded normal, but my computer wasn't recognizing it, and Disk Utility wouldn't load when it was plugged in. I tried restarting with and without the disk,  mounting, unmounting, all of the above recommendations.

"unmount" led to "the disk is already unmounted or has a partitioning scheme...."

"mount" and "eject" said the attempt timed out.

"mountDisk" said it was successfully mounted, but I still couldn't access it, and "unmountDisk" would be successful as well, but no luck to "mount" or "mountDisk" afterwards.

I finally found the order that worked.

```
diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk2
diskutil eject /dev/disk2
```

then I just plugged it back in to my computer and we were golden.
Thanks for all your help everyone.

Comment: Volume timed out while waiting to eject

Comment: One or more volume(s) failed to mount

Comment: I've been trying to figure this out for literally years and have read hundreds of suggestions. This is the one that worked for me.

Comment: I was having the exact same issue where `unmountDisk` would work fine but `eject` would result in the "timed out" message.
I finally found a suggestion to see if `fsck` was holding the disk hostage. A quick `ps aux | grep fsck` revealed that indeed it was hijacking the disk/volume as soon as it was plugged in. `sudo pkill -f fsck` (or just `kill` with the PID if you prefer) immediately allowed the volume to be mounted.

Comment: @ArielAllon Thanks! Your comment was just as important as the answer.

Comment: @ArielAllon I've been looking for this solution for 2 years.  I love you.

Comment: P.s. feel free to upvote my answer below: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/314628/54512

Comment: My flash drive had 2 partitions (shown by `diskutil list`), `diskutil eject disk2` timed out while `diskutil eject disk2s1` succeeded and device had been removed from the list. Will be able to open it then.

Comment: @ArielAllon even after killing fsck it won't let it mount. It keeps re-launching fsck_hfs and taking up to 50% cpu usage but never finishes checking. I've waited for 12 hours.

Comment: Stereof and @ArielAllon you guys are heroes!

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the help! I tried everything, including the fsck stuff but it didn’t work… then, I gave it up, browsing for a new highend SSD because this made me sick! Suddenly, I heard the hard drive working!… something had happened by itself, just after waiting some time. I just like to add this, maybe it helps others, too.

Comment: thank goodness Apple makes everything so easy!

Comment: worked as a charm!

Answer (score 69):

I'd recommend checking if `fsck` is holding your disk hostage upon connection. This was it for me.

Running `ps aux | grep fsck` revealed:

```
root              2587   7.3  0.1  4363584  21780   ??  U    10:56PM   2:22.54 /System/Library/Filesystems/exfat.fs/Contents/Resources/./fsck_exfat -y /dev/rdisk2s1
```

So the solution was a `sudo kill -9 2587` (insert your PID instead of 2587) (or `sudo pkill -f fsck`).
As soon as that ran, my Volume immediately mounted.

Oh the irony of `fsck` being the problem...

Addendum (from a related [question/answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/314629/54512)): Ideally, you're better off letting `fsck` run its course. Otherwise, you'll run into this the next time too.

Comment: > sudo kill -9 PID solved my problem. Though the volume now is read-only and the system suggest to format it as soon as possible, at least i could copy all the content. Thanks to Ariel Allon & patrix

Comment: @AlejandrodelRío Awesome, glad it helped! On a related question/answer (https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/268998/external-hard-drive-wont-mount/314629?noredirect=1#comment407437_314629) I made the note that if you do let `fsck` run its course (might take a few hours) it should complete and allow read/writes again.

Comment: I did this, but the drive was read only. I had to repeat this process after ejecting since the drive won't mount. I ended up repairing the disk (formatted exFat) and it went back to working as normal.

Comment: Wow, this was my problem! I knew something was locking the drive but had no clue what. Thanks! And shame on Apple (Mac Os) for not providing some type of feedback if fsck is running.

Comment: I had fsck running as well, but killing it just caused it to restart.  I waited until the next day.  fsck completed and the disk worked fine.

Comment: essentially every time you disconnect the external drive without ejecting, MacOS will quietly run fsck on that drive next time you plug it in. For a large  drive it will take a while...without any info whatsoever. The irony of Apple's UI being the problem :)

Comment: What if I have no sudo permission? Is there any way to kill `fsck` process? This is my office MacBook

Comment: @alramdein I just updated my answer with a further clarification. If possible, you're actually better off letting `fsck` run its course, even if it takes a long time.
I'll let others comment with ideas about how to kill it without root (i'm not aware of a way).

Comment: this saved me, thanks

Answer (score 8):

If you can see it in `diskutil list`, locate its identifier (comes in the form of `/dev/diskx`) and run:

```
diskutil mountDisk /dev/diskx
```

while replacing `/dev/diskx` with your disk identifier.

If even that does not work,

```
diskutil mountDisk readOnly /dev/diskx
```

will mount your disk as read-only so that you can get your data off in the case that you have corrupted your disk's partition table (*very, very unlikely caused by hard-unplugging your disk*). If so, you will need to format your hard drive, through the steps found [here](https://www.maketecheasier.com/format-external-drive-osx/), along with the man page obtainable through `man diskutil` if you need more information.

Comment: `One or more volume(s) failed to mount` for both commands. Thanks anyway

Comment: @charles try mounting the problematic partition alone, with `diskutil mount /dev/diskxsy`

Comment: @charles do also try the `readOnly` option

Comment: `Volume on disk2s2 timed out waiting to mount` with and without `readOnly`.

Comment: All answer are not working for me except this with `readOnly` option. After mount in `readOnly` mode, I have ejected with `finder` and physically remove-plugin usb cable again: it works!

Answer (score 3):

That has happened to me many times. Go to Launch Pad, Disk Utility, and select the disk that won't mount. Then select Repair.

Comment: Lol. I selected unmounted disk volume, clicked "Restore" and after confirmation dialog was showed it suddenly appeared as mounted without even restoring !?

Comment: "Repair" means reformat your drive. Don't do that.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Failed mount, eject and repair. Windows saved my life. I plugged the external hard disk to a Windows laptop. Copy a file from the external hard disk to the desktop and cut the file in the desktop and paste(replace) back to same location in the external hard disk. Ejected the external hard disk properly from the Windows PC and plugged it to my Macbook. Problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

**Easy solution**. Following steps fixed the issue for me:

**1.** Run the following command to check that nothing is blocking disk mounting:

> ps aux | grep fsck

**2.** If *fsck* is using the disk, you need to kill the process.

For example for this result:

[image]

Kill the process running the following command:

> sudo kill -9 1536

**3.** Here the disk is mounted and you'll be able to use it. You can check it on Finder, but to avoid repeating all previous steps each time you use the disk, continue with following steps.

**4.** Eject the disk from Finder like always, with up arrow

[image]

**5.** After ejecting the device from Finder, you'll see *fsck* running again same command used on step 1. So you'll need to wait for *fsck* finish, before disconnecting the disk. This took me around 27 mins for 1Tb disk. Then, the disk will work like always

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I also waited for some time after connecting the disk. It did not mount for like 10 minutes, but after an hour it was mounted by itself (for 5Tb disk).

Answer (score 1):

did you try, first of all, to repair the volume looking for errors with disk utility (or terminal)?

Comment: Disk utility is not fully starting. The message `Loading disks` never ends. How can I do it with the terminal?

Comment: diskutil verifyvolume *mountpoint*
and
diskutil repairvolume *mountpoint*

Comment: `diskutil verifyDisk /dev/disk2`
Started partition map verification on disk2
Checking prerequisites
Checking the partition list
Checking the partition map size
Checking for an EFI system partition
Checking the EFI system partition's size
Checking the EFI system partition's file system
Checking the EFI system partition's folder content
Problems were found with the partition map which might prevent booting
Error: -69854: A disk with a mount point is required

Comment: Repair says, `Repairing the partition map might erase disk2s1, proceed? (y/N)`. How are the chances I loose the content of the disk?

Comment: before to do that, check that your gpt map is still ok with 

sudo gpt show -R *disknumber*

Comment: sudo gpt show -l disk2
gpt show: disk2: Suspicious MBR at sector 0
       start        size  index  contents
           0           1         MBR
           1           1         Pri GPT header
           2          32         Pri GPT table
          34           6         
          40      409600      1  GPT part - "EFI System Partition"
      409640        2008         
      411648  3906549760      2  GPT part - "CHARLES-HDD"
  3906961408        2015         
  3906963423          32         Sec GPT table
  3906963455           1         Sec GPT header

Comment: disk2s1 is your EFI partition, that's okay to erase. Your data should remain where it is

Comment: -R, not -L, to check the partition type (not the partition name), would be better to see an image of the terminal output

Comment: -r or -R are not working (`gpt: illegal option`).

Comment: $ gpt show disk2
gpt show: disk2: Suspicious MBR at sector 0
       start        size  index  contents
           0           1         MBR
           1           1         Pri GPT header
           2          32         Pri GPT table
          34           6         
          40      409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
      409640        2008         
      411648  3906549760      2  GPT part - EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7
  3906961408        2015         
  3906963423          32         Sec GPT table
  3906963455           1         Sec GPT header

Comment: This was without -l

Comment: well, it seems that you have a windows gpt partition table, with a single 2tb partition, but I'm not confortable with windows systems and I am not sure that OS X can solve your problem flawlessy

Comment: I would first do a backup of the whole disk (you can use dd command)

Comment: Ok thanks, this will not work because the 2TB are full and I don't have any other hard drives. Is there a chance that diskutil repairDisk works?

Comment: I don't think that OS X can handle such partition as it would do with hfs partitions however you can try gdisk utility from https://sourceforge.net/projects/gptfdisk/ but I am not familiar with that, I just know it has "generic" repair (non destructively) features even for windows gpt partitions

Answer (score 1):

I run into this problem today and I finally solve it by **eject the disk first**. after that you can **successfully mount the disk with no error**.

```
diskutil eject /dev/diskx
diskutil mount /dev/diskx
```

Comment: downvote with no reason annoying me, why don't you point up what is wrong with my answer

Comment: both commands timeout or fail

Comment: Volume timed out while waiting to eject

Answer (score 0):

My solution.
After unplugging HDD drive without properly ejecting it, the drive became invisible in Finder when plugged it again. Also Disk Utility did not show any drives at all while this drive was connected. Reboot was not helpful.

First solution. Earlier in such case I plugged the drive to Windows PC and after fixing there it started working also on Mac.

However I was interested to return it to life only on Mac.

So the solution in my case (Mac mini M1, Sonoma 14.0).

1. A command "ps aux | grep fsck" in Terminal gives PID of the drive and then
2. A command "sudo kill -9 PID"
3. I repeated "ps aux | grep fsck" and find new PID for the drive.
4. Made again "sudo kill -9 PID". At this point the drive disappeared in fsck (see a picture).
5. After that I was able to start Disk Utility and my HDD appeared there.
6. Started First Aid. It was successful.
7. Pressed Mount, and the HDD appeared in Finder.

[image]