# Seagate External Drive Won't Mount

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, mount, data-recovery

I am very much a newbie here, but saw something on StackExchange that someone here might be able to help me with. I have a Seagate 2TB portable that I use as a backup drive for my 2017 Macbook. It was working fine and I left it for about an hour while it was backing up. When I came back there were 3 or 4 "Improperly ejected" error messages.

When I tried to reconnect the drive Finder would not recognize it. However, I can see it in DiskUtilities, but it shows as Unmounted and when I click "Mount" nothing happens, and I get this error message "Could not mount “Seagate”. (com.apple.DiskManagement.disenter error 0.)"

I went through all the troubleshooting steps with Seagate technical support, including running their "Premium Recovery Suite" but they were not able to help me either. I have started looking at Data Recovery Companies, but saw the following on your site. [External drive does not mount after plug off without eject](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/235309/external-drive-does-not-mount-after-plug-off-without-eject?newreg=4cee7690e026485eabe7dcfac33acf22)

> > 

5

If you can see it in diskutil list, locate its identifier (comes in the form of /dev/diskx) and run:

diskutil mountDisk /dev/diskx
while replacing /dev/diskx with your disk identifier.

If even that does not work,

diskutil mountDisk readOnly /dev/diskx
will mount your disk as read-only so that you can get your data off in the case that you have corrupted your disk's partition table (very, very unlikely caused by hard-unplugging your disk). If so, you will need to format your hard drive, through the steps found here, along with the man page obtainable through man diskutil if you need more information.

> > 

Is this potentially something that might work for me and my drive? I don't want to risk damaging the disk further and losing the data, but also don't want to pay $500-$1500 to recover my data.

If this is a potential I may need someone to walk me through how to do this. I have not used terminal commands since MS Dos days.

Thanks for any help you can give me on this!

TDGooldy

Comment: Sorry to say but it *sounds* like a failure of the drive or USB controller in the drive case. Especially as Seagate couldn't help you fix it. It may be time for a data recovery company to have a crack at the drive. Tho those can be expensive...

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little confused. Clarifying question: If this is a "backup drive" for your 2017 MacBook… did something happen to your 2017 MacBook? Isn't all of your data on the MacBook?

Comment: Yes, this is a back up drive. My Macbook only has a 512 GB drive, so I had backed up 15 years of pictures onto the Seagate backup drive to make space on my Macbook. I also backed those pictures up to the cloud (or at least I thought I did) only to find the folders empty. The Seagate drive is my only copy of those 1,000s of pictures. Hope that helps to clarify.